# Nominal effects variables - is it ok to interpret z value?

Tags: ordinal-data, ordered-logit

Is it appropriate to report the statistical significance of the threshold coefficients for variables in a clm model that were calculated with nominal effects?

Using the example from the ordinal package clm() vignette from the wine data:
[image]

Although nominal effects weren't really necessary for the contact variable here, I'm using it for a simple reproducible example.

Because z values are provided in the output, would it be acceptable/correct to convert those to p-values and say something to the effect of "Contact for the 1|2 threshold is NOT statistically significant at the 0.05 level (z value -1.390 = p-value of .16) but the effect is significant at the 2|3 threshold (z value -2.559 = p value .010).